# how to get selected records count in rich data table having multiple pages rich:datascroller

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am facing a problem where i want to test that whether a user has selected any record or not from the multiple page in rich:dataTable. These pages are created through rich:datascroller. Related code is given below.

```
            <rich:datascroller id="dataScroller" selectedStyleClass="myClass" renderIfSinglePage="false"
                align="center" for="dataList" maxPages="10" 
                 pageIndexVar="currentPage" pagesVar="totalPages" reRender="pageNum,dataList" ajaxSingle="false">
                <f:facet name="first"><h:outputText value="First" /></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="last"><h:outputText value="Last" /></f:facet>
            </rich:datascroller>
            <h:inputHidden id="pageNum" value="#{currentPage}"></h:inputHidden> 
            <h:inputHidden id="numOfRows" value="10"></h:inputHidden>
```

The problem is that if user selects a record (say on 3rd page) and after that he moves to page one. Now in this case when i try to  iterate through the table in Java Script to know that whether he has selected any record or not than it always allows me to iterate till the current page on which i am and hence i am unable to give user the proper alert message for selecting a record first on pressing of submit button. All i want is to know that user has checked the check box against a record on any page from the available pages , irrespective of the fact that on which page is currently opened.  Any ideas?

Comment: If the user moves away then you should treat it as if he didn't select anything, shouldn't you?

Comment: no i want to show him the alert message only when he presses the submit button after completing his selection on all pages

Comment: I don't think I understand, can you give me a use-case? The user comes to the table, what is he doing with it? (Or what do you want the user to do?)

Comment: Actually the page on which i have this Rich:dataTable has many other fields too, but selecting a record from the available records in the rich:dataTable is must for sucessful persisting of the change. Now if user has done all the mandatory work but have not selected a record from the rich:dataTable and presses the submit button, in this case i have show him an alert message that you forgot to select a record from table. Now as this page contains more than one pages (due to the use of rich:datascroller) and user can select any record on the available pages and presses the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it via the [Richfaces Javascript API](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#JavascriptInteractions).

For every component you have in your page, there's a representing Javascript object, named as next:
`Richfaces_componentId` (small 'f' for faces).
Using that and to understand it live, go to the [ScrollableDatatable Live Demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/scrollableDataTable.jsf?c=scrollableDataTable), open your chrome browser console, and execute this:

```
 Richfaces_ScrollableGrid_j_id353_carList.selectionManager.selection.ranges
```

This will print out an empty javascript array.
Try selecting some rows, and running that line again, you'll have an array containing the indexes of your selected rows.

So to put that in a function:

```
<script>
    function tableHasSelection() {
         return Richfaces_ScrollableGrid_j_id353_carList.selectionManager.selection.ranges.length != 0;
    }
</script>
```

Now you call this function via `onclick` of your submit button, and `return false` in case of no selection to prevent submission.
Of course you would replace `Richfaces_ScrollableGrid_j_id353_carList` with your component's javascript representing object.
Hopefully this will help.

[UPDATE]

According to our discussion in the comments, here is an update that might be helpful.
Your data table would be like this:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable value="..." var="element" id="table" selectionMode="..." selection="...">
     <rich:column>
         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="..." onclick="toggleSelection(this, #{element.id});" />
     </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{...}" onclick="return tableHasSelection();" />
```

And your script would have these functions:

```
<script>
    var selectedElements = [];
    function toggleSelection(checkbox, id) {
         if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
             //add selected row if checkbox is checked
             selectedElements.push(id);
         } else {
             //or find it in the array and remove it
             var index = selectedElements.indexOf(id);
             if (index > -1) {
                 array.splice(index, 1);
             }
         }
    }

    function tableHasSelection() {
         return selectedElements.length != 0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Qussay thanks for your time... but my problem is that i want to make decision on the basis of a check box agains every row in the table. Any check box from all the available rows and all pages in the rich:dataTable is checked than i ll persist all the checked records, but if user has not checked any check box  on all page than i have to show him an alert message.... and i am using the rich:dataTable and have to stick with it...

Comment: ok, then I would create a global scope javascript array, and add selected elements to it on every checkbox selection, and on submission I would check the length of that array.

Comment: @QussayNajjar the docs and the demo are for RF 3.3.x, it doesn't work that way in RF 4

Comment: @bilal I've updated the answer accordingly to your comment, honestly as a validation-wise solution, I find this the most optimized solution.
Let me know if it still doesn't solve your issue

Comment: Qussay... thanks for you time. This is what i want and it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

(`<rich:extendedDataTable>` has selectable rows, you may want to look at that)

One thing you can do is to submit the selection when the user clicks it. E.g.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="saveSelection(#{rowId})">

…
<a4j:jsFunction name="saveSelection">
    <a4j:param name="id" assignTo="#{bean.selectedId}">
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

But if the user will only be choosing one row then simply say if the selected row is not on the current page the user didn't select anything, I don't think that's a wrong approach.

Comment: @Makhiel.... in you approach we will always have server trip on each check box selection where as user can select as many records he wants... so it would be bit costly in performance and i am doing all that to increase the performance.....

Comment: If you expect multiple selections on multiple pages then I'm not sure using pagination is the right approach. The point is that you'll have to use an extra field to "remember" what user selected, it can be a hidden input field, that way you won't have to talk to server.